# AWS Gateway API and file response

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Is it possible for AWS Gateway API to respond with a file (zip file) from a HTTP endpoint integration? I heard somewhere AWS Gateway API doesn't support binary formats but wasn't sure if that was for input or input and output.

I have an existing HTTP endpoint and I want to add AWS Gateway API over it; it currently returns a file (zip) on the response.

Comment: I think what you heard is right: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=195218

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot respond with a Zip(any binary type) file using API Gateway so far. (As stated in [AWS official forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=689737#690056))

As a work around, you can store your file on S3 and dispatch the link of the file using API Gateway.

Comment: So a HTTP proxy integration type with content passthrough doesnt support content type application/pdf or application/x-zip-compressed being returned? Or are you saying this is just a limitation with Lambdas.

Comment: This is not a lambda limitation. And by concept an API does not return binary files but URL pointing to it.

Comment: That is a concept yes but not one useful for our implementation.  Thanks for your response Thomas ; do you know if there are any official Amazon links on this subject?

Comment: Just added the link to official AWS forum in my answer. No official documentation about it so far TMK.

Comment: Good news, binary data is now supported by API Gateway: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/11/binary-data-now-supported-by-api-gateway/

Answer (score 0):

Binary payloads are not yet natively supported as API Gateway currently encodes content as UTF-8. For the purposes of serving files, serving them via S3 may be an appropriate workaround. You could configure your API to return a link to S3 or to redirect to the public S3 URL.

Thanks,
Ryan